# How to check if a UIElement is visible in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

How can I check if any given UIElement is currently visible on the UI?

There is the UIElement.Visibility property, but this is set by the progammer to indicate that the element should be hidden or visible.

I already check if the element is in the VisualTree.

All this does not help if there is another element on top that overlaps it.

WPF has a property UIElement.IsVisible that seems to do the job, but this is missing in Silverlight.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do some code to test the [`Visiblity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`HitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) property of an element.

**EDIT:**

Try to do something like mentioned here,
 [`Silverlight - Determine if a UIElement is visible on screen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658042/silverlight-determine-if-a-uielement-is-visible-on-screen)

Comment: I already tried that but it does not solve the problem. If you have a TextBlock that is overlapped by a Grid (so that the user can not see the TextBlock), it is possible that Visibility is Visible and HitTestVisible is true.

Comment: Yes, it is visible, is not that you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes. But in this case the TextBlock is NOT visible on the UI because there are other controls on top of it.

Comment: can you post the xaml?

Comment: I don't use XAML. I'm looking for a generic solution that works with any Silverlight-UI. But I'll post an example.

Comment: My question is why do you want to have a textblock behind a grid? your question does not make sense

Comment: This was just an (theoretical) example. Of course I don't want that. My question makes sense indeed. I want to check if an element is visible for the user or not. What's wrong with the question? =)

Comment: now only i got your question,check the link i have added in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check the "render visibility" (although it cannot check for overlapping elements):

Elements do have the `Unloaded` event.
It is raised whenever changes to the VisualTree happen that result in the Element being part of a VisualTree branch that is not currently rendered. But luckily you don't have to listen for those events because only loaded elements do have decendants or a parent in the VisualTree.
And with the help of a nice little `ExtensionMethod` you can check whether an element is loaded or not at any given point in time:

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLoaded(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return element.GetVisualChildren().Any();

        //I'm not sure if this alternative is better:
        //return System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element)!= null;
        //or
        //return element.GetVisualParent() != null;

    }
}
```